# What is a gauge (for someone who has not studied gauge theory)?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

I am taking a Quantum Mechanics II course and we were studying the relativistic corrections to the hydrogen atoms in perturbation theory. I was looking at the assignment, and a question is as follows:

> Consider the non-relativistic Hamiltonian for a charged particle $-e$, in presence of an external, constant and uniform magnetic field $$B=\hat{e}_3B_0$$ in the symmetrical gauge $A=0.5B \times r $

But I don't understand what a Gauge is in this context. If I wish to find the Hamiltonian, what information is that supposed to give me? Could you explain to me what a gauge is for someone who has not had gauge theory, or link me to some basic bibliography to learn it?

Comment: Have you taken a course in electromagnetism?

Comment: yes, i have taken a course in electromagnetism. Next semester I will take electromagnetic theory, so my understanding is relatively basic

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146585/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There are many choices of $\vec A$ that lead to the same $\vec B$. Such choice is called a gauge.

Answer (score 1):

A Hamiltonian of a particle in electromagnetic field is typically expressed via the 4-potential of electromagnetic field, which is defined up to a [gauge transformation](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantum/node35.html). The gauge in your case fixes the 4-potential.

Comment: @my2cts : I do not disagree, but I don't quite see your point. This does not seem to be in contradiction with my answer.

Comment: @my2cts: So why don't you post your comment as an answer?