# Gauge fixing terminology (math terms)

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, gauge-theory, definition, gauge

In the majority of the sources I've read regarding gauge fixing, the authors sometimes use (IMHO) a vague terminology. Let's take the case of the magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}$ defined as
$$ \vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A} \tag{1} $$
The magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}$ is not unique because when one applies this transformation
$$ \vec{A} \longmapsto \vec{A}+\nabla\psi \tag{2} $$
computing $\nabla \times \vec{A}$ will yield the same $\vec{B}$ as (1). A typical gauge fixing condition (at least I think that's how it is called) is the Coulomb gauge
$$ \nabla\cdot\vec{A}=0  \tag{3} $$
which serves to simplify many calculations.

What is somewhat clear to me: the *transformation* (2) is called a **gauge transformation** and the *equation* (3) is called a **gauge fixing condition**. What is not clear:

- Which is the gauge? Is it the particular choice for $\psi$ or the one for $\vec{A}$ in (2)? If the second statement is true, then what would we call the particular choice for $\psi$?
- To make things even more complicated the equation (3) is sometimes called "the Coulomb gauge", although I suspect this might be a terminology abuse.

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: We say some quantity or expression is "in the X gauge" if we have applied the "X gauge fixing condition" to it. I don't know a standard name for what $\psi$ is.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146585/2451

Comment: The gauge is the scalar and vector potential together. It is together because QFT is a relativistic theory. Thus a  gauge transformation changes them in a coherent manner whilst a gauge fixing sets them to particular values or a range of values. In fact, in the geometric description of gauge theory, the gauge is described as a connection form on a bundle.

Comment: The Coulomb gauge is a specific choice of gauge fixing. It's basically a case of terminological elision rather than of abuse. But of course the latter term is often used to mean elision isca form of terminological abuse.