# Why Coulomb gauge is a possible gauge choice?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

In classical field theory we can get, that adding gradient of some scalar field to magnetic vector potential does not change the physics at all. So, we have such a symmetry:

$\boldsymbol{A}\rightarrow\boldsymbol{A}+\nabla f$

Then there is such a thing written almost in every book on elecrodynamics:

> "For example, we can use Coulomb gauge $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{A}=0$."

I can't understand this implication. Why this symmetry allow us to say, that divergence is zero? What is $f$ in this case?

Comment: *"What is f in this case?"* - Have you tried writing down $\nabla\dot(A+\nabla f) = 0$ and *solving* for $f$ in terms of $A$?

Comment: The symmetry allows one to constrain a degree of freedom.  There are many ways to do that.

Comment: $∇ \cdot (A+∇f)=0 $ gives a poisson equation which can be solved for $f$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129819/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

> Why this symmetry allow us to say, that divergence is zero?

Stipulate a vector potential with non-zero divergence

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}\ne 0$$

'Gauge away' the divergence

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}'=\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{A}+\nabla f \right)=0$$

and it follows that

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}+\nabla^2f=0\Rightarrow\nabla^2f=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}$$